# Divergência na leitura

Tags: c, arduino, serial

Fiz um sketch para Arduino MEGA, onde recebe dados pela Serial2 e exibe na Serial, a comunicação acontece mas o byte enviado não é o mesmo que o recebido, por exemplo:

Envia 0x01, recebe 0x7F
Envia 0x99, recebe 0x33

```
    void setup()
    {
      Serial.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1);   //Monitor
      Serial2.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1);  //Leitor

      Serial.println("Waiting...");
    }

    void loop()
    {
      byte data;

      if ( Serial2.available() ) {
        Serial.println("Leitor...");

        do { 
          data = Serial2.read();

          Serial.print("0x");
          Serial.println(data, HEX);
        } while (Serial2.available());

      }
}
```

Tentei mudar a configuração para 8N2, 7N1 entre outras mas a serial enviando como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não é a primeira vez que tento ler algo por outra serial do MEGA que não seja a zero e acontece o mesmo.